# How to execute an AGI script during a call by pressing a key

Tags: asterisk

I want to trigger an AGI script (to activate a door opener) while calling. Preferably the script executes on pressing the #-key.

How to embed this behavior in a dialplan? All examples I have found are not dependent on a key press.

I am using FreePBX 2.8.1.4. This is what I have tried:

```
exten => s,1,Wait(1)
exten => s,n,AGI(test.py)
exten => s,n,Dial(SIP/mk55/203,20,tr)
exten => #,n,AGI(/home/pi/.scripts/dooropen.py)
exten => s,n,Hangup()
```

and this:

```
exten => s,n,Read(inPut,,1)
exten => s,n,Dial(console/dsp)
exten => s,n,GotoIf($["${inPut}" = "#"]?keypressed,1)
exten => keypressed,1,AGI(/home/pi/.scripts/dooropen.py)
exten => s,4,Hangup
```

Answer (score 0):

In deed AGI(script_name, args...) is the right application to use https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Application_AGI

To retrieve a DTMF press you can use WaitExten https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Application_WaitExten

You can find here a sample of WaitExten usage 
[Seek Help concerning IVR Menu in Asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925621/seek-help-concerning-ivr-menu-in-asterisk)

Regards